# multiply matrix using threads in c

Tags: c, matrix

I have a problem with my try of writing code using threads to multiply matrixes. I have no warnings (I compile with std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -lpthread) but when I try to use my code I always got problems with core dumped.
I place my code here and beg you for any tips because I'm really close to get insane. I have no idea what can I fix. I inspired [this link](http://zhaowuluo.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/pthread-atrix-multiplication-on-unixlinux/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "pthread.h"

int xA;
int yA;
int xB;
int yB;
int xC;
int yC;
int* mA;
int* mB;
int* mC;
pthread_t* thread;
int numOfThread;
int **ap = &mC;
int **A = &mA;
int **B = &mB;

int* allocResultMatrix(int xA, int yB, int *xC, int *yC){

    *xC = xA;
    *yC = yB;

    return (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) *(*xC * *yC));
}


void makeMatrix(int **ar, int x, int y){

   *ar = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) *(x * y));
   int k = -1;
   int range = 1000;      

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
            (*ar)[++k] = rand() % range;
        }
    }  
}

void* multiply(void* slice){

    int s = (int)slice;
    int from = (s * xA)/numOfThread;
    int to = ((s+1) * xA)/numOfThread;


    for (int i = from; i < to; i++){  
        for (int j = 0; j < yB; j++){
            ap[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < yA; k++){
                ap[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
       }
    }
return 0;
}



void printMatrix(int *ar, int x, int y)
{
    int k = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        printf(" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
                printf("%9d", ar[++k]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }  
    printf("\n");

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc == 6){


    printf("\n");



    numOfThread = atoi(argv[1]);



    if(atoi(argv[2]) > 0 && atoi(argv[2]) <= 10000 && atoi(argv[3]) > 0 && atoi(argv[3]) <= 10000 && atoi(argv[4]) > 0 && atoi(argv[4]) <= 10000 && atoi(argv[5]) > 0 && atoi(argv[5]) <= 10000 ){
        xA = atoi(argv[2]);
        yA = atoi(argv[3]);
        xB = atoi(argv[4]);
       yB = atoi(argv[5]);

    }
    else {
        printf("bad dimensions");
        return 0;
    }


    if(yA != xB){
        printf("yA should be equal with xB\n");
        return 0;
    }





    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    makeMatrix(&mA, xA, yA);
    printMatrix(mA, xA, yA);
    makeMatrix(&mB, xB, yB);
    printMatrix(mB, xB, yB);
    thread = (pthread_t*) malloc(numOfThread * sizeof(pthread_t));
    mC =  allocResultMatrix(xA, yB, &xC, &yC);



    for (int iterator = 1; iterator < numOfThread; iterator++){


        if (pthread_create (&thread[iterator], NULL, multiply, (void*)iterator) != 0 ){
            perror("er!\n");
        free(thread);
            return 1;
        }
}

multiply(0);

for (int i = 1; i < numOfThread; i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

printf("\nresult\n");
    printMatrix(mC, xC, yC);
free(thread);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to analyze the core dump.

Comment: Don't bother writing this code, it's been written plenty of times before.  For example: https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/wiki/FastCMatrixMultiplicationUsingPThreads and http://heshans.blogspot.sg/2009/05/matrix-multiplication-using-pthread.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating single dimensional array, and trying to access it as two-dimensional one.

In particular, expression `ap[i][j]` in `multiplyMatrix` assumes you have an array of pointers to array of integers, which is not the case.

If check run your code with Klocwork or similar tool, you will notice that `ap[i][j]` is valid only for values `i=[0..xA*yB]` and `j=0`.

You can allocate two dimensional arrays:

```
int **allocate(int x, int y)
{
   int **result = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
   for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
   {
      result[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Or multiply with single dimension:

```
int s = (int)slice;
int from = (s * xA)/numOfThread;
int to = ((s+1) * xA)/numOfThread;

for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
{  
  for (int j = 0; j < yB; j++)
  {
    ap[i * yB + j] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < yA; k++)
    {
      ap[i * yB + j] += A[i * yA + k]*B[k * yB + j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried and it still doesnt work. For example with 2nd option I got: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)